# Is it possible to use CSS nth-child to follow this pattern?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is what I'm currently using to select certain items...

```
            .col {
                &:nth-child(21),
                &:nth-child(22),
                &:nth-child(43),
                &:nth-child(44),
                &:nth-child(65),
                &:nth-child(66),
                &:nth-child(87),
                &:nth-child(88),
                &:nth-child(109),
                &:nth-child(110) {
                    width: 100%
                }
            }
```

Is it possible to create a :nth-child selector that allows me to select these same items without having to write them all out as I have here?

I tried 21n + various numbers, but I can't seem to figure it out without the grid breaking. I assume two nth-child selectors would be required as the pattern is generally an increment of 21 + 1 more (then repeated).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be using a class for this purpose, this way produces more style only, which would have been so simplified by using a class.

the css selectors (22n-1) and (22n) should work here, in this case.

Comment: Adding a class adds the same amount of bloat to the markup that writing all the individual :nth-child() selectors does. What would simplify this... is the solution you have now provided.

Comment: Using nth-child selector as you have done works too, but you have to write all possible css child rules, which might get a little messier as the no of childrens get large.

Your rules will be compiled to n no of seperate css rules , which is not good than adding a simple class to the markup, less effort , less addition of strings does same thing.

Comment: the css selectors (22n-1) and (22n) should work here, in this case. This is best case scenario here.

Comment: **This is what your style rule gets compiled to**

.col:nth-child(21), .col:nth-child(22), .col:nth-child(43), .col:nth-child(44), .col:nth-child(65), .col:nth-child(66), .col:nth-child(87), .col:nth-child(88), .col:nth-child(109), .col:nth-child(110) {
  width: 100%;
}

**USing a class produces**
.some-class{
 ....rules
}

Comment: This works perfectly. I was going to add a class, but responsively the grid changes and so it was going to be easier to create a new rule rather than a class that becomes redundant as soon as you're off the desktop size. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy coding !!